# How to show glossaries

Tags: glossaries, sharelatex

How do I show glossaries in sharelatex?

Here is my simplified document.

My `main.tex`:

```
\input{header}

\makeglossaries   
\input{glossar}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter


\begin{abstract}
In dieser Arbeit wurden die Zusammenhänge zwischen der Knochendichte, Porosität und dielektrischer Permittivität von Spongiosa untersucht.
\end{abstract}

%\listofacronyms
%\listofsymbols
\printglossaries



\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

Die komplexe Permittivität \underline{\gls{Perm}} eines Materials kann in der folgenden Form ausgedrückt werden: 


\glsaddall

\backmatter
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\literature

\end{document}
```

My `header.tex`:

```
%!TEX root = main.tex

\documentclass[a4paper,
        color,
        nocolortitle,
        twoside,    
        german, %nogerman
        serifmath,
        12pt,
        noproprietaryfonts,
        thesis,
        ] {tudbook} 

% Typographie
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Sprachanpassungen
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

% Bild- und  Tabellenunterschriften
\usepackage[twoside, margin={0.5cm,0.5cm}]{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,noitemsep}

% Formeln und Mathe
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\addto\extrasgerman{\sisetup{locale=DE}}
\def\mathbi#1{\boldsymbol{#1}}

% Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Referenzierung
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=HKS41-30]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

% Einbindung ganzer PDF-Seiten
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Farbige Absätze
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,hyperref=true,backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}

% Zeilenabstand
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

% Spaltenabstand
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.3pc}



\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep,noitemsep}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

My `glossar.tex`:

```
\newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{{\epsilon}},description={Komplexe relative Permittivität des Mediums}
unit={$\frac{F}{m}$},
 type=symbolslist}
```

The minimal example works, but not the one with the header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\title{EjGlos}

\begin{abstract}
In dieser Arbeit wurden die Zusammenhänge zwischen der Knochendichte, Porosität und dielektrischer Permittivität von Spongiosa untersucht.
\end{abstract}



\newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{{\epsilon}},description={Komplexe relative Permittivität des Mediums}
unit={$\frac{F}{m}$}}


\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{1}

Die komplexe Permittivität \underline{\gls{Perm}} eines Materials kann in der folgenden Form ausgedrückt werden: 

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Also sharelatex.com/project/5955f9a5ade7f36849037653 
It is public and editable.

Comment: From ShareLaTeX site: "To compile a document that contains a glossary in ShareLaTeX you don't have to do anything special, but if you add new terms to the glossary once you compiled it, make sure to click on Clear cached files first under logs option). "

Comment: Hi TeXnician, thank you for your answer. I cleared cached files under logs option, but still nothing is shown, no glossaries and even not a header for glossaries, although it showes header for figures, tables, literature.

Comment: Would you please make one MWE instead of three code snippets? That helps us help you.

Comment: You can make one MWE by using `filecontents` take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) at the bibliography stuff in that answer, which you might use for your files.

Comment: Hi, the header is not mine, i got it as a template, i really cant edit it. https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5955f9a5ade7f36849037653 i made it public, deleted any additional files, i could delete. Take a look at it, pls.

Comment: something minimal workes of course, but doesnt work with the header.

Comment: You have `\input{glossar}` before `\usepackage{glossaries}`. That ought to have triggered an "undefined control sequence" error. Move `\input{glossar}` after `\makeglossaries`.

Comment: Thank you for your answered, placed it right after, but still doesnt show the Glossary.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}`.

Comment: ok, i placed, but still didnt show

Comment: Search the `.log` file for `runsystem`. Does it say if the system command was executed?

Comment: BibTeX The file 'output.bcf' does not contain any citations!,  Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--16, seems to be nothing about glossary

Comment: but there was no runsystem entry in log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `tudbook` class automatically loads `glossaries` with the `xindy` option (and also does `\makeglossaries`¹ so you can remove `\usepackage{glossaries}` and `\makeglossaries` from your `header.tex` file).

The `.glg` transcript file contains the error:

```
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string


*** Unable to execute: '"xindy"  -L german -C din5007-utf8 -I xindy -M "output" -t "output.glg" -o "output.gls" "output.glo"' ***
```

From the [`glossaries` FAQ](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#charindex0):

> **What does the xindy error "CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string" mean?**
>
> `xindy` discards all commands and braces from the sort string. If your
>   sort string (either specified by the `sort` key or the `name` key) only
>   consists of commands, this will be treated by `xindy` as an empty sort
>   string, which produces an error message in newer versions of `xindy`.
>   For example, the following will cause a problem:
>
> ```
> \newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},  
>   description=alpha}
> ```
>
> Either use a different sort key for the entry, for example:
>
> ```
> \newglossaryentry{alpha}{sort=alpha,  
>   name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},  
>   description=alpha}
> ```
>
> or, if all entries are like this, you may prefer to use the `sort=use`
>   or `sort=def` package options. See the [Sorting Options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sortingoptions) section of the
>   user manual for further details of the sort option.

So you need to add a `sort` key to your entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{{\epsilon}},description={Komplexe relative Permittivität des Mediums}
unit={$\frac{F}{m}$},
sort={epsilon},
 type=symbolslist}
```

The reason you don't get a problem with your MWE is because that's using `makeindex` instead of `xindy`.

---

¹I don't recommend this practice in class files as there are some commands that must be placed before `\makeglossaries`, such as `\newglossary`, so this class won't allow you to define your own custom glossaries.

Comment: thank you so much, i made my entire student project, 50 pages, and this was the only thing that was missing and i couldnt figure out, i spend soo much time on it. really it helped so much.

Comment: only the unit doesnt appear \newglossaryentry{Perm}{name=\ensuremath{{\epsilon}},description={Komplexe relative Permittivität des Mediums}
unit={$\frac{F}{m}$},
sort={epsilon},
 type=symbolslist}   or like this: unit={\ensuremath{\frac{F}{m}}}}

Comment: ok, now everything works with unit={\si{m}}  and  \glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit  }{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit} in glossar.tex